# How to read DeveloperSettings in Android

Tags: android, android-developer-api

I want to read the DeveloperSettings like - Bluetooth HCI snoop capture enabled/disabled.
Does Android provide an API for user applications to read this information. Is there a listener to which user space app can register and get a callback when value of DeveloperSettings change?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can access some of the properties on the Settings using for example :`Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.BLUETOOTH_ON,0);`

I'm not sure about all the features available for developers. Also some of them need root to be modified.

Comment: I am specifically trying to read Settings.Secure.BLUETOOTH_HCI_LOG .